# Recursive function on stack

Tags: c, recursion, stack, iteration

I have a very simple function to find out the max, non negative value of a stack of integers. I would like to transform this function to a recursive one.
There are several points to keep in mind:

- Before running the function, we have initialized `num`, but have not assigned any value to it. And please, we should not rely on the fact that C will automatically assign 0 to `num` under certain conditions
- After running the function the stack `s` is empty and we have the **maximum non negative value** stored in `num`
- I'm a beginner in C and data structures, so please be nice :)

This is the iterative function:

```
void max_stack(stack *s, int *num){
    *num = 0;
    int aux = 0;
    while (!emptyStack(*s)){
        aux = top(*s);
        pop(s);
        if (aux>*num){
            *num = aux;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why you'd want to transform this to a recursive function, when the solution you have now is better fit for C than the recursive function would be...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Homework requirements maybe?

Comment: @AnttiHappala: I am trying to understand recursion better and would like to get more fluent getting from iterative functions to recursive and the opposite. That's it.The purpose of this question is for learning.
The restrictions I enumerated are to ensure that the two functions are 100% equivalent.

Comment: *"we have initialized num, but have not assigned any value to it. "* - having a hard time consolidating what that *means*. If it's *initialized*, it has a determinate value. Also, `num` is a *pointer* in this code, and is *dereferenced*, so it had *better* contain a valid address. If you're talking about the dereferenced value, then you certainly assign to it via `*num = 0;` Finally, your iterative function both finds the maximum *and* empties the stack. That was intentional? You said that was the end-result, but just clarifying here.

Comment: @WhosCraig
What I meant is that before calling the function we have just this:
    
    int number;
    /*We also have a stack of integers "example_stack" set up which may be full or empty */
   /*We now call the function*/
   max_stack(&example_stack, &number);
   /*We should now have example_stack empty and the max positive value in the stack stored in number*/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match *exactly* the iterative code provided, we must also match the assumption that, even on an empty stack, `0` is the minimum value that will be stored in the target parameter.

With that:

```
void recursive_max_stack(stack *s, int *num)
{
    if (emptyStack(*s))
    {
        *num = 0;
        return;
    }

    int lhs = top(*s);
    pop(s);

    recursive_max_stack(s, num);

    if (lhs > *num)
        *num = lhs;
}
```

**Explanation**

First, we need a default case (when there are no elements in the stack). Just like your iterative function, the default case stores zero as a result.

```
if (emptyStack(*s))
{
    *num = 0;
    return;
}
```

So we need to save off the current stack top in the current frame, then pop that off the stack (remember, we keep it in a local variable):

```
lhs = top(*s);
pop(s);
```

Once that is done, we can recurse.

```
recursive_max_stack(s, num);
```

When returning from the recursion, each `lhs` is compared with the content of `*num` (which was set to `0` when we hit maximum depth). If greater, `lhs` replaces the value stored at `*num`.

```
if (lhs > *num)
    *num = lhs;
```

This continues up the call stack as we unwind invokes, finally returning to the initial invoke, then to the caller, with `*num` now holding whatever the largest non-negative value in the stack was, or zero if all values were negative (or the stack was empty).

That's it. This does not care what original value was stored in `*num`. It is eventually replaced by `0` upon reaching maximum recursion depth, then replaced *again* whenever the ensuing frame has a `lhs` value greater than the current stored value in `*num`

Comment: Excellent explanation. The only doubt I have is why do we need the `return;` after `*num=0`

Comment: @Peter Putting everything *past* that in an `else` block would make that return moot. It's just a style choice. You can do it either way, but you should NOT just remove the `return;` and leave the code otherwise as-is. It won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The way this will work is if the stack is not empty then it will keep calling itself passing the largest value onward. Once the stack is empty the functions will return one by one returning the largest value through the num pointer;

Here in pseudo code:

```
void max_stack(stack *s, int * num){
    int aux = 0;
    if(!emptyStack(*s)){
        aux = top(*s);
        pop(s);
        if (aux > (*num)){
            (*num) = aux;
        }
        max_stack(s, num);
    }
}
```

When first calling this function you'd call it like so:

```
int num = 0
max_stack(s, &num);
```

Comment: @Josep I also fixed a bug from the previous version

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. But note that the function is not 100% equivalent to the iterative function I posted. The key point is that the "void" function should be insensitive to the initial value of num: all we can do before calling the function is `int num;`

Comment: @Josep well since num is a pointer it should still work if I changed the prototype to void